# WebService ASMX ASP.net No aparece metodo

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, web

Estoy teniendo un problema al querer agregar métodos a los ya existentes.
Tengo un proyecto con un servicio **asmx**, con una línea

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/RUBConsultasSP.cs" Class="RUBConsultasSP" %>
```

En la clase ***RUBConsultasSP.cs***, tengo todos los métodos que estoy usando.

Estoy agregando métodos y no aparecen al ejecutar el servicio.

Ya limpié, recompile, reinicié, actualice referencias y no hay forma de que aparezcan los métodos que incorporé en la clase.

De hecho, no actualiza el **wsdl**.

¿Alguien sabe por qué puede ser?

Comment: Hola Marcelo. Sería de gran ayuda que pongas parte de tu código para revisarlo. Por lo que indicas, puede ser un tema de Interfaz de servicio, pero sin ver lo que llevas, no se puede confirmar si ese es el problema.

Comment: Solo has agregado el markup del servicio, si colocas el resto del codigo seria mejor, recordando obviar datos sencitivos. adicional te recomiendo que realizes el [tour] para que ganes tu primera medalla y tbn te leas [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve trabajando en otros temas y deje de lado esta consulta q había hecho. Ahora cuando la retomé vi q se soluciona borrando los archivos temporales de .net.
Se soluciono en c:\windows\Microsoft.net buscar el framework con el q se esta trabajando y borrando los archivos dentro de la carpeta Temporary ASP.net Files